# iron-ajax with basic auth not working

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to make a request from my polymer frontend to my java-jersey backend using iron-ajax, but can't seem to work out a way to do basic auth without hardcoding it as an attribute. I don't know where to write the header-making method so that it gets used by the iron-ajax. I tried putting it both inside and outside Polymer({}) and still it doesn't get called. Here's my code. Please help. Thanks.

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

    <dom-module id="activity-feed">
        <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
            .cont{ height:90vh; overflow: auto;}
    core-list .row{height: 80px;padding: 16px}
        </style>
        <template>
        <div class="cont">
            <iron-ajax
            auto
            url="http://localhost:8080/tip/webapi/home"
            handle-as="json"
            method="GET"
            headers='{"Authorization": {{makeheaders(gi,tanu)}}}'
            last-response="{{gogo}}"
            ></iron-ajax>
            <div>{{gogo.id}}</div>              
            </div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is : "activity-feed",
            makeheaders: function(user,pass){
                console.log('ceva tot se intampla');
            },
        });
        function makeheaders(user, pass) {
            console.log('merge functia');
            return "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your iron-ajax element is set to "auto" which kicksoff the api request at startup. You could remove the auto attribute, and define an combined observer for user and pass to calculate the header, then manually send the request:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="activity-feed">
    <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
        .cont{ height:90vh; overflow: auto;}
core-list .row{height: 80px;padding: 16px}
    </style>
    <template>
    <div class="cont" >
        <iron-ajax
        id="xhr"
        url="http://localhost:8080/tip/webapi/home"
        handle-as="json"
        method="GET"
        headers='[[headers]]'
        last-response="{{gogo}}"
        ></iron-ajax>
        <div>{{gogo.id}}</div>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is : "activity-feed",

        properties: {
            headers: {
                type: Object,
                value: function() { return {}; }
            },
            user: String,
            pass: String
        },

        makeHeaders: function(user,pass){
            return "Basic " + window.btoa(user + ":" + pass);
        },

        observers: ['_setBasicAuth(user, pass)'],

        _setBasicAuth(user, pass){
            // might be needed
            this.headers['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
            // this sets your Auth header
            this.headers['Authorization'] = this.makeHeaders(user, pass);
            this.$.xhr.generateRequest();
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! So the reason it didn't work is because of the 'auto' attribute? I'm very new to JS, so if you could also tell me how to trigger the request (manually or otherwise), that'd be awesome.

Comment: Of course iron-ajax also works in auto mode. You only have to fiddle around with generating the base64 string inline. I'm not sure about the correct syntax for an inline definition in the headers param of the iron-ajax element. I would stick the observer or an computed binding w/o hard coded credentials

Comment: Ok, right now it's not doing anything. If at all possible, might you let me know what I need to do to fire the request? I would like to know the command as it applies to the above code for credentials: user: hau, pass: les. And if you could put it inside the example you already gave me, that'd be great. Thanks a billion!

Comment: the request is fire with `this.$.xhr.generateRequest()` in _setBasicAuth(). The observer is executed when both properties user and pass have a value. To get it running, insert your custom element in your HTML, give it an id attribute and set user/pass properties: `var a = document.getElementById('idOfYourElement'); a.user='hau'; a.pass='les';`

Comment: Where do these commands go? Is it inside Polymer({here?}) or outside? Can you please just write it on the code above? (your code, not mine.) Thanks!

Comment: Put the code I mentioned before in your application HTML where you include your element and where you create an instance of `<activity-feed id="idOfYourElement"></activity-feed>`

Comment: In the parent component, I did: <activity-feed id="acti"></activity-feed>  and then, <script>Polymer({
  is: "al-meu",
 }
 });
 
 var a = document.getElementById('acti'); a.user='gi'; a.pass='tanu';</script>     The console says: al-meu.html:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of null